# Passivate Highcharts Export Phantom JS Web Server?

Tags: phantomjs, highcharts

I refer to http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/render-charts-serverside.

> You can also let the script start a web server. By doing so, we don't have to start a PhantomJS process over and over again for every conversion job and this results in a better performance. While running the script in web server mode, the result isn’t saved to a file, but returned as a base64 string, unless when you want to export to SVG or PDF.

I have successfully done so, but I was wondering if there are any ways to passivate the server when it is not required, and activate the server whenever I send a request to the SVGConverter?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot trigger server remotely, so the server requires to be enabled.

Comment: The reason I am asking this is because I realised JBoss slowed down significantly after having PhantomJS running in the background.  jBoss will eventually run out of memory as the poolCleaner() in AbstractPool class gets invoked more and more times due to the scheduler. Are there any other ways to go around this problem?